# How are you supposed to write attributes with null values in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Im using linq to xml to write out a little config file for an application and was a little surprised to discover XAttributes dont accept null as their value - they throw an exception instead.

Null is a perfectly valid value for many of the properties in my config and I dont want to have to null check attributes everywhere:

```
            var attribute = _element.Attribute(attribute);
            var value = attribute == null ? null : attribute.Value;
```

A further reason I dont want to write code like this is that it will make it easier to mis type names of things - eg if an attribute is spelled wrong it will just act like an attribute that exists but has a null value rather than throwing an exception.

The solution I have at the moment is as follows but it seems a little bit ugly + like something you shouldnt need to do.

I've knocked up a little class to make it a bit easier to write + read xml and am using a string containing just the null character to signal a null string.

I've omitted everything except the indexer for brevity:

```
public class XContainerWrapper
{
    private readonly XElement _element;

    public XContainerWrapper(XElement xElement)
    {
        _element = xElement;
    }

    public string this[string attribute]
    {
        get
        {
            var value = _element.Attribute(attribute).Value;
            return value == "\0" ? null : value;
        }
        set
        {
            var valueToWrite = value ?? "\0";
            _element.Add(new XAttribute(attribute, valueToWrite));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really wouldn't start including the Unicode U+0000 character. Can you just omit attributes with no values? What about just using an *empty* attribute value?

Comment: just discovered that using the empty character doesnt work - that produces an exception when trying to write the XDocument

Comment: as mentioned above I'd rather not omit attributes.  I could use the empty string as the value for null, (wont cause me any problems here) but I'm surprised you cant make a distinction between null and empty as sometimes they can have different meanings.

Comment: You do realize you can cast `XAttribute` to `string`, and if you start off with `null` you'll get a `null` string reference back, right? So the snippet of code you gave can be as simple as `var value = (string) attribute;`. Fundamentally, I think you *should* omit the attributes, rather than inventing your own convention. To avoid typos I would create constants with the attribute names, and use them everywhere.

Comment: fair enough.  I suppose that's the convention for XNames for elements anyway

Comment: There's no such thing in XML as a null value. What do you actually want? The attribute to be absent? Or to be present with the value "" (zero-length string)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension method instead of XAttribute Value getter:

```
public static class XmlExtensions {
  public static string SafeValue(this XAttribute attribute) {
    var value = attribute == null ? null : attribute.Value;
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```
XAttribute a = null;
var value = a.SafeValue();
```

Comment: Otherwise known as: `var x = (string) attribute;`. No need to reinvent the wheel here.